# ScrollTo (jquery) does not work in Firefox and Prestashop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

The scrollTo jQuery works in Prestashop Chrome and Safari

But it is not working in Firefox.

My html

```
<li class="sendtofriend">
    <a href="javascript:$.scrollTo('#qnaTab',1000,{offset:-75})">Pregúntanos</a>
</li>
```

Firefox error:

> blank html page with text -> [object Object]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind it to the `click` event and not give in `href`, not a good idea.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);"
   onclick="$.scrollTo('#qnaTab',1000,{offset:-75}); return false;">
```

Also I would advice you to do in a non-obtrusive way:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="go">
```

```
$("#go").click(function () {
  $.scrollTo('#qnaTab',1000,{offset:-75});
  return false;
});
```

The above code is much cleaner.